# Restart Django instance running with Supervisor and uwsgi

Tags: django, uwsgi, supervisord

Currently I use `/etc/init.d/supervisor restart` but this restarts all processes under supervisor. Is there a clean way to restart just one django instance?

I remember with modwsgi you just needed to touch the wsgi file but it doesnt seem to work with uwsgi.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open supervisor shell and restart there:

```
$ sudo supervisorctl
>>> restart <process_name>
```